# porque manda este error ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save() al intentar guardar?

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

tengo la siguiente tabla que muestra un listado de personas y al hacer click sobre una fila, me manda a otra pagina

```html
<p:dataTable var="consultaPersona" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.listNivelesPersona}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros." selectionMode="single" selection="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1}"
  rowKey="#{consultaPersona.persona.cveIdPersona}">

  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.mostrarPantallaHorario}" />
  <p:column headerText="No.Empleado">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.noEmpleado}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="RFC">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.rfc}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Nombre">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.nombre}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Ubicacion">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin} -#{consultaPersona.unidadAdministrativa.desUnidadAdministrativa}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Entrada">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.horarios.horarioEntrada}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Salida">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.horarios.horarioSalida}" />
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la otra pagina, tengo un boton que al hacer click muestra un dialogo que contiene la info de esa persona seleccionada

```html
<p:dialog header="Establecer Horario" widgetVar="modalHorario" modal="true" height="300" width="600px" appendTo="@(body)">

  <h:outputLabel value="Horario" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="35" height="1" />
  <p:selectOneMenu id="horario" autoWidth="false" style="width:155px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.horarios.cveIdHorario}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{HorariosComponent.listHorarioss()}" var="horario" itemValue="#{horario.cveIdHorario}" itemLabel="#{horario.horarioEntrada} a #{horario.horarioSalida} Tolerancia #{horario.toleranciaRetardo} Falta #{horario.toleranciaFalta} ">
    </f:selectItems>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
  <br></br>
  <h:outputLabel value="Ubicación" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
  <p:selectOneMenu id="ubicacion" autoWidth="false" style="width:155px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{UnidadAdministrativaComponent.listUnidadAdministrativas()}" var="ubicacion" itemValue="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" itemLabel="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin} - #{ubicacion.desUnidadAdministrativa}">
    </f:selectItems>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Inicio" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
  <p:calendar id="popup" placeholder="Fecha Inicio" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.fecInicioNivel}" />
  <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Fin" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="25" height="1" />
  <p:calendar id="popup1" placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.fecFinNivel}" />
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <h:outputLabel value="Obs." styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="50" height="1" />
  <p:inputText placeholder="Observaciones" />
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaLunes}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Lunes" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaMartes}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Martes" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaMiercoles}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Miercoles" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaJueves}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Jueves" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaViernes}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Viernes" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaSabado}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Sabado" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaDomingo}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Domingo" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1.checaFestivo}" />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Festivo" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
  <p:spacer width="10" />
  <h:outputLabel value="Debe registrar E/S en Biometrico" styleClass="estiloletra" />
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <p:commandButton styleClass="botonAsistencias" value="Cancelar" style="width: 100px;" oncomplete="PF('modalHorario').hide();">
  </p:commandButton>
  <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
  <p:commandButton styleClass="botonAsistencias" value="Guardar" style="width: 100px;">
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.saveNivelesPersona(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona1)}" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('modalHorario').hide();" />
  </p:commandButton>

</p:dialog>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en ese dialogo tengo un boton de guardar, que manda a llamar al siguiente metodo

```
@Transactional
public String saveNivelesPersona(NivelesPersona nivelespersona1) {

    System.out.println("ENTRO AL METODO DE GUARDADO0");

    NivelesPersona nivelespersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersona2(nivelespersona1);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaHorarios(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), horarios);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaPersona(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), persona);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaUnidadAdministrativa(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), unidadadministrativa);

    return "/jsf/bienvenido.xhtml";
}
```

y sale  ese error en consola
y es que los objetos horarios, persona y unidad vienen nulos, es como si de mi vista no recogiera esos valores de mi p dialog, ya los inicialize y se los setie a mi objeto nivelespersona1, pero aun asi no los toma

```html
 //Metodo inicializa
    @Transactional
    public String newNivelesPersona() {
        
        nivelespersona1 = new NivelesPersona();
        horarios = new Horarios();
        unidadadministrativa = new UnidadAdministrativa();
        persona = new Persona();
        nivelespersona1.setHorarios(horarios);
        nivelespersona1.setUnidadAdministrativa(unidadadministrativa);
        nivelespersona1.setPersona(persona);

        //Se obtiene la unidad fisica de la sesion
        unidadFisica = (Integer) getSession().getAttribute(Constantes.UNIDAD_FISICA);

        //Se obtiene las personas que se encuentran en la misma unidad fisica
        listNivelesPersona = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaByUnidadAdmin(unidadFisica);

        return RUTA;
    }
```

lo raro es que si yo no inicializo esos objetos no me sale ningun error, pero si yo le muevo a mi tabla la propiedad selection que hace referencia a mi objeto de nivelespersona1, que es el mismo objeto donde recupero los valores en mi p dialog, si le cambio el nombre de ese objeto en la tabla, ya me sale el error de que debo de inicializar los objetos horraios, unidadadministrativa y lo hago, pero al mostrar el p dialog ya no me muestra cargada la info de esa persona a menos de que le vuelva a poner el objeto nivelespersona1 a la propiedad selection y no entiendo por que lo hacer
que es lo que esta fallando y hace que no recupere el valor?

Comment: Cómo tienes definida la clase `NivelesPersona`?

Comment: @E.Betanzos, la puse como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scope("session")
```

@Component("NivelesPersonaComponent")

public class NivelesPersonaComponentImpl extends BaseBean implements NivelesPersonaComponent {

```
private NivelesPersona nivelespersona;
private NivelesPersona nivelespersona1;
private UnidadAdministrativa unidadadministrativa;
private Persona persona;
private Horarios horarios;

@Autowired
private NivelesPersonaService nivelesPersonaService;
```

@Autowired
   private PersonaService personaService;

```
//variables
private List<NivelesPersona> listNivelesPersona;
private List<NivelesPersona> listNivelesPersona2;

private String nombreRol;
private Integer unidadFisica;
private Long numEmpleado;
private String nombreEmpleado;
private String unidadAdministrativa;
private String puesto;
private String horario;
private String toleranciaRetardo;
private String toleranciaFalta;
private String cordinacionAdmin;
private boolean muestraHistorial;
private String tipoPersonal;
private int cvePersona;

private static final String RUTA = "/jsf/consultaEmpleadosAdscritos/consultaEmpleadosAdscritos.xhtml";
private static final String RUTA2 = "/jsf/consultaEmpleadosAdscritos/muestraInfoEmpleadosAdscritos.xhtml";

//Metodo inicializa
@Transactional
public String newNivelesPersona() {

    nivelespersona1 = new NivelesPersona();
    horarios = new Horarios();
    unidadadministrativa = new UnidadAdministrativa();
    persona = new Persona();
    nivelespersona1.setHorarios(horarios);
    nivelespersona1.setUnidadAdministrativa(unidadadministrativa);
    nivelespersona1.setPersona(persona);

    //Se obtiene la unidad fisica de la sesion
    unidadFisica = (Integer) getSession().getAttribute(Constantes.UNIDAD_FISICA);

    //Se obtiene las personas que se encuentran en la misma unidad fisica
    listNivelesPersona = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaByUnidadAdmin(unidadFisica);

    return RUTA;
}


@Transactional
public String saveNivelesPersona(NivelesPersona nivelespersona1) {

    System.out.println("ENTRO AL METODO DE GUARDADO0");

     System.out.println("horarios" +horarios);
    System.out.println("unida" +unidadadministrativa);
    System.out.println("persona" +persona);

    NivelesPersona nivelespersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersona2(nivelespersona1);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaHorarios(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), horarios);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaUnidadAdministrativa(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), unidadadministrativa);
    nivelesPersonaService.saveNivelesPersonaPersona(nivelespersona2.getCveIdNivelPersona(), persona);

    return "/jsf/bienvenido.xhtml";
}
```

y NivelesPersona

```
@Table(schema = "SICOIN", name = "NIVELES_PERSONA")
```

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "sicoin/mx/gob/sre/sicoin/domain", name = "NivelesPersona")
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "sicoin/mx/gob/sre/sicoin/domain")
public class NivelesPersona implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CVE_ID_NIVEL_PERSONA", nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@Id
@XmlElement
Integer cveIdNivelPersona;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_LUNES")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaLunes;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_MARTES")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaMartes;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_MIERCOLES")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaMiercoles;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_JUEVES")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaJueves;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_VIERNES")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaViernes;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_SABADO")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaSabado;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_DOMINGO")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaDomingo;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CHECA_FESTIVO")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean checaFestivo;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "IND_ACTIVO")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Boolean indActivo;
/**
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "FEC_INACTIVO")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Date fecInactivo;
/**
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "FEC_INICIO_NIVEL")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Date fecInicioNivel;
/**
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "FEC_FIN_NIVEL")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Date fecFinNivel;

/**
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "CVE_ID_UNIDAD_ADMIN", referencedColumnName = "CVE_ID_UNIDAD_ADMIN") })
@XmlTransient
UnidadAdministrativa unidadAdministrativa;
/**
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "CVE_ID_PERSONA", referencedColumnName = "CVE_ID_PERSONA") })
@XmlTransient
Persona persona;
/**
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "CVE_ID_HORARIO", referencedColumnName = "CVE_ID_HORARIO") })
@XmlTransient
Horarios horarios;
```